# what could we see if we . .

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is the following use of "could" compatible with "light"?

> What **could** we see if we **light** a lantern?

This doesn't seem to fit any of the textbook conditional patterns.

Comment: Imho it's perfectly valid to ask questions like *What **could** go wrong if I **do** that?* as opposed to *What **can** go wrong if I **do** that?* or *What **could** go wrong if I **did** that?* But I must admit the ***fourth*** permutation *(What **can** go wrong if I **did** that?)* doesn't sit so well with me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["If I do that" vs "if I did that."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184636/if-i-do-that-vs-if-i-did-that)

Comment: @FumbleFingers No. What kind of conditional is the sentence in the OP?

Comment: "Numbered conditionals" are just a crude attempt to describe ***some*** of the ways English can create "conditional" clauses. Native speakers rarely know or care about them anyway, since they're not particularly useful concepts. But if you *have* to categorise an utterance that doesn't match the more common forms that you *do* know, you can probably just file it under "**mixed** conditional".

Comment: Imho, knowing "the conditional number" for *any* utterance is completely pointless unless the reason you need to know that is in order to ***understand*** the text. But I assume you do understand the exact meaning of your example text, so I don't really see the point of the question here. Bear in mind that the meaning would be exactly the same if your text had used explicit Past Tense instead of "subjunctive": *What could we see if we **lit** a lantern?* Why should you care if that changes the "number", since it doesn't change the ***meaning**?*

Comment: (And I still think that earlier question ***is*** a duplicate, which ***should*** resolve your issue! :)

Comment: Consider this: "What could we do if we become/became superheroes?" Would you say both "become" and "became" work?

Comment: Yes, those are just more examples of exactly the same choice of verb form. Note that I'm calling *What could we do if we **become** superheroes?* a "subjunctive" usage because so far as I'm concerned it's effectively "the same as / short for" *What could we do if we **were to become** superheroes?*

Comment: I'm guessing OP's doubt is about the apparent oil-and-water mix of unreal ("could") and real ("light"). The answer to this is that although "could" is the past (and therefore unreal) version of "can", it can also be used in a real sense, so there's no conflict.

Comment: @gotube Exactly. I suspect that, unlike the "light" sentence, the "superheroes" sentence works well only with "became" and "could," with the "could" used in an unreal sense.

Comment: Your question has attracted three close votes. If you want to keep it open, please **edit** and **give more details**  as to why you are asking. In other words, say that the tenses used in the sentence seem to conflict with what you know about conditional tenses. Give an example or say why you think the construction is ungrammatical to help clarify.

Comment: I would focus on the meaning of the sentence and ask how would it change if the past tense of *light* i.e. **lit** were used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FumbleFingers is correct in the comments that there's no list of conditional forms in English, and from a grammatical perspective, it makes no sense to talk about them any more than it makes sense to have a list of verb forms that can be conjoined with "and". Both of us have railed against this belief elsewhere on the site -- and here I go again.

Some time ago, English teachers invented and named (first, second, third, mixed, etc.) a small set of the most common conditional structures to give students an easier time producing correct conditional sentences reliably *until the students understand the verb forms well enough to create their own*. This set in no way limits the conditional structures available to an English speaker. I've never seen a catalogue of them all, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's a hundred. And creating such a catalogue would be pointless except to demonstrate that it's not worth learning them, and certainly a mistake to limit yourself to them.

There is only one rule in conditionals that I've derived and teach as absolute: ***you can never mix an unreal condition with a real result, and vice-versa***. If you understand the meaning and function of verb forms -- including how to form unreals, you're free to combine them as you wish, so long as they don't violate that one rule.

To your example sentence:

> What could we see if we light a lantern?

It might appear that "could" is unreal, while "light" is clearly real. Although "could" can be the past (and therefore unreal) version of "can", it can also be used in a real and present sense. There is a sense of "could" that means *real possibility*, so there's no conflict.

Also, I'm struggling to think of a natural scenario where the example question makes sense, so let's replace it with something easier to place in a context:

> What could we do with the apartment if we move to Tibet?

Here, I think it's clearer that "could" suggests a list of real options that may arise from the real possibility of us moving to Tibet.